# Recursive constexpr function

Tags: c++, recursion, constexpr, decltype, effective-c++

I was reading Effective Modern C++ and wanted to try out a very basic function using constexpressions. My C++ skills are really not great, but I can't figure out what is wrong with this basic code:

```
constexpr int test( int x ) {
  // works if: return x == 43337, otherwise segmentation fault
  return x > 1000000 ? x+1 : test( x + 1 ); 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  constexpr auto x = 0;
  cout << "Result: " << test( x );
  return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, this code works if I use return x == 43337, but any larger value causes a segmentation fault.

What is wrong with this code? If I understand the constexpressions correctly, the computation should be on compilation, however it seems to me computation takes place during runtime. And larger values seems cause a segmentation fault, because the call stack gets too deep.

However, I'm not sure why I'm not receiving any compiler errors, since the computation should take place at compile time( apparently not ).

Additionally, would this code work if I the method signature looks like this:

`constexpr decltype(auto) test( int x )`

Comment: You understand that the compiler has to at-compile-time trigger this function 1000000 times? I have some doubts that it can handle it.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this function in a constexpr-context? Otherwise you just have a recursive function that will likely make you run out of heap space.

Comment: BTW: Your example works just fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T69M6P

Comment: Or: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wx3vhP

Comment: @ALX23z Does not seem to be a problem. OP even states that there's no compiler error.

Comment: @SimonKraemer thank you, you were right on your first comment. But it's kinda weird that it works on  gcc.godbolt.org/z/T69M6P :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are not calling `test` in a context that requires compile time evaluation, and so the compiler is free to evaluate the call at run-time, leading to a segfault.

You could force a compile time context for the call to `test` by using the result to initialize a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr auto result = test( x );  // error
```

This gives a [compile time error](https://godbolt.org/z/h58W19) as expected:

```
error: constexpr variable 'result' must be initialized by a constant expression
  constexpr auto result = test( x );
                 ^        ~~~~~~~~~
note: constexpr evaluation exceeded maximum depth of 512 calls
...
```